# how to create a perfect 5x5 table using <div> tag, which looks like using <table> tag

Tags: html, css

I have created many tables using `<table>` tag but don't know how to get the same result using `<div>` tag. I have been trying the same but not got success yet. I am trying the perfect table of 5x5 using `<div>` tag, u know - same border, same size..and no gap between the borders.

Appreciate if somebody share the `<div>` code. Thanks.

Comment: If you're representing tabular data, use a table. Otherwise, are you just trying to create a grid?

Comment: Table tags aren't deprecated. Use them for their intended purpose, which is to make tables.

Comment: oh..so div can't help giving me same look and feel which <table> gives??

Comment: @Tyler - i have been playing with <div> here and there in the code but didn't got what exactly i wanted. Correct me if I am wrong - <div> is used to get grid sort of tables..

Comment: @jsborn17: They can...but if you're trying to make an actual *table*, you shouldn't be using divs.  It's *layout tables* (tables whose sole purpose is to arrange stuff) that are deprecated, not tables themselves.  If you have stuff that's naturally in rows and columns, and the rows and columns have meanings, then what you have is a bona-fide table, and it should be coded as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this example. But if your purpose is tabular data, just use tables and not `div`s.

http://jsfiddle.net/BvuhZ/

Comment: perfect !! this is what i needed, figuring it out..thanks buddy :)

Comment: If you like this answer, you should accept it by clicking the outlined checkmark under the vote-down arrow.

Comment: i am actually new to stackoverflow.com, hope i have successfully submitted the acceptation..

Comment: @David - but why the top line in the table just goes on..it has happened with me always when i tried before. any comments?

Comment: @jsborn17 I added `float: left;` and `overflow: hidden` to the table container. Floating it will make the parent only as big as its children, and I added overflow so it expands to fit all the children. http://jsfiddle.net/BvuhZ/1/. For future reference, if you are going to ask a question accept an answer if it helps you...